# doParallel performance on a tensor in R

Tags: r, performance, tensor, doparallel

I need to perform some operations on a tensor and I would like make this parallel.
Consider the following example:

```
# first part without doParallel

N = 8192
M = 128
F = 64

ma <- function(x,n=5){filter(x,rep(1/n,n), sides=2)}


m <- array(rexp(N*M*F), dim=c(N,M,F))

new_m <- array(0, dim=c(N,M,F))

system.time ( for(i in 1:N) {
        for(j in 1:F) {
            ma_r <- ma(m[i,,j],2)
            ma_r <- c(ma_r[-length(ma_r)], ma_r[(length(ma_r)-1)])
            new_m[i,,j] <- ma_r       
        }
    }
)
```

This takes around 38 seconds in my laptop.
The following is with doParallel:

```
# second part with doParallel

library(doParallel)  
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1  
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, type="FORK")  
registerDoParallel(cl)


calcMat <- function(x){

    n <- dim(x)[1]
    m <- dim(x)[2]

    new_x <- matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=m)

    for(j in 1:ncol(x)) {
        ma_r <- ma(x[,j],2)
        ma_r <- c(ma_r[-length(ma_r)], ma_r[(length(ma_r)-1)])
        new_x[,j] <- ma_r       
    }

    return(new_x)

}


system.time ( a_list <- foreach(i=1:N) %dopar% {
    m_m <- m[i,,]
    new_m_m <- calcMat(m_m)
 }
)


Y <- array(unlist(a_list), dim = c(nrow(a_list[[1]]), ncol(a_list[[1]]), length(a_list)))
Y <- aperm(Y, c(3,1,2))


stopCluster(cl)
```

This second one takes around 36 seconds.
So I do not see any improvement in terms of time.
Does anyone know what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be aware of certain things when you want to use parallelization.
The first one is that there is an overhead due to communication and possibly serialization.
As a very crude example,
consider the following:

```
num_cores <- 2L
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores, type="FORK")
registerDoParallel(cl)

exec_time <- system.time({
    a_list <- foreach(i=1L:2L) %dopar% {
        system.time({
            m_m <- m[i,,]
            new_m_m <- calcMat(m_m)
        })
    }
})
```

In my system,
`exec_time` shows an elapsed time of 1.264 seconds,
whereas the elapsed times in `a_list` each show 0.003 seconds.
So in a very simplified way we could say that 99.7% of the execution time was overhead.
This has to do with [task granularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity_(parallel_computing)).
Different types of tasks benefit from different types of granularity.
In your case,
you can benefit from *chunking* your tasks in a *coarse* way.
This basically means that you group the number of tasks in a way that reduces communication overhead:

```
chunks <- splitIndices(N, num_cores)
str(chunks)
List of 2
 $ : int [1:4096] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ : int [1:4096] 4097 4098 4099 4100 4101 4102 4103 4104 4105 4106 ...
```

Each chunk has indices for several tasks,
so you need to modify your code appropriately:

```
exec_time_chunking <- system.time({
    a_list <- foreach(chunk=chunks, .combine=c) %dopar% {
        lapply(chunk, function(i) {
            m_m <- m[i,,]
            calcMat(m_m)
        })
    }
})
```

The above completed in 17.978 seconds in my system,
using 2 parallel workers.

EDIT: as a side note,
I think there's usually no good reason to set the number of parallel workers to `detectCores() - 1L`,
since the main R process has to wait for all parallel workers to finish,
but maybe you have other reasons,
perhaps maintaining system responsiveness.

Comment: Also, you might want to look into the [bigmemory package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory).

Comment: this is an array with 3 dimensions, I do not understand how bigmemory package could be useful since it is for matrices.

Comment: I have tested your solution and it works. I can save 30% of the time. However I was hoping for a bigger improvement. Any other idea?

Comment: Not for `foreach`. If performance is critical, you should look into migrating your logic (from the first solution without `doParallel`) to C++, using `Rcpp` and maybe `RcppParallel`.

Comment: Are you sure you're creating the `chunks` with your desired value of `num_cores`? I do think you should be able to save more than 30% if you have more than 2 cores.

Comment: I have only tried with 2 cores since you wrote me that is not worth to use more than 2.

Comment: That is not what I meant, I meant to say that I would just set `num_cores` to `detectCores()`, without the `-1L`.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed that your code works if you set cluster type to "SOCK"

```
cl <- makeCluster(numberofcores, type = "SOCK")
```

Note: On Windows this does not work, I used the doSNOW package (have found that it has better compatibility on multiple OS)

The following runs much faster

```
library(parallel)
library(doSNOW)

numberofcores = detectCores()  # review what number of cores does for your environment

cl <- makeCluster(numberofcores, type = "SOCK")
# Register cluster so that caret will know to train in parallel.
registerDoSNOW(cl)

system.time ( foreach(i = 1:N) %dopar% {
  for(j in 1:F)  {
    ma_r <- ma(m[i,,j],2)
    ma_r <- c(ma_r[-length(ma_r)], ma_r[(length(ma_r)-1)])
    new_m[i,,j] <- ma_r       
  }
}
)

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: use foreach(i=1:N,.packages = c('foreach','doParallel')) instead of simple for loops.