# doParallel(): Caching values into a pre-defined environment [Windows]

Tags: r, windows, foreach, scoping, doparallel

I would like to understand the "doParallel" package more. Im playing around with environments. I would like to create a global environment `.someEnv<-new.env(parent =  emptyenv())`outside of `foreach() %dopar%{…}`

I know that foreach() needs to import all packages, functions, values and data to the `foreach()`-function using `.export= “”` and `.packages=””`.

My question is, is there a ways to import a Global environment into `foreach()`, read and write into this environment and use it as a way to cache calculations? (please no Comment on cacheing calculations using .Rdata, .RDS, .feather etc)

here is an example:

```
require(doParallel)
library(doSNOW)
getDoParWorkers()
getDoParName()
cl<-makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
getDoParWorkers()
getDoParName()

#define environment
.someEnv<-new.env(parent =  emptyenv())
.someEnv$var<-1:10
.someEnv$squared<-matrix(nrow=10)

#define Function for "foreach"
do.something<-function(x)
{
  .someEnv$squared[x]<-.someEnv$var[x] *.someEnv$var[x]   
   return(.someEnv$squared[x])
}

foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% do.something(i)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Error Message:

```
Error in do.something(i) : 
  task 1 failed - "Objekt '.someEnv' nicht gefunden"
```

Comment: If you want to cache something that is common between parallel sessions, you need something on disk I'm afraid.. Or more complicated approach based on message passing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `doSNOW` and `doParallel` are two different packages that provide backends for `foreach`.
You can certainly test both,
just don't get confused.
The following works for either,
but your question is more closely related to the usage of the `parallel` package
(which is included with R).

Your approach will not work because even if you put your environment in each parallel worker,
they will be copies that are modified independently:

```
foreach(i = 1L:2L) %dopar% {
    .someEnv$hello <- "world"
    .someEnv$hello
}
[[1]]
[1] "world"

[[2]]
[1] "world"

print(.someEnv$hello)
NULL
```

However, you can use the `bigmemory` package:

```
library(doParallel)
library(bigmemory)

cl <- makeCluster(4L)
registerDoParallel(cl)

var <- 1L:10L

squared <- big.matrix(nrow = 10L, ncol = 1L, type = "integer")
# show by coercing to normal matrix
squared[,]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

squared_desc <- describe(squared)
# assign it to each worker's global environment
clusterExport(cl, c("squared_desc"))

foreach(i = 1L:10L,
        .noexport = c("squared_desc"),
        .packages = "bigmemory") %dopar%
        {
          squared <- attach.big.matrix(squared_desc)
          squared[i] <- var[i] * var[i]
          NULL
        }

stopCluster(cl); registerDoSEQ()

squared[,]
[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

Note that the matrices from `bigmemory` are strictly typed internally,
so if you define them to be integers,
you should assign to them values that are integers,
which are explicitly specified in R by appending `L` at the end of a number,
otherwise you'll get a warning about downcasting.

Also, you don't need to coerce the whole `big.matrix` to use it,
but almost every time you access its elements you'll be copying some data into a regular R matrix/vector.

EDIT: and finally, I think `bigmemory` doesn't provide any synchronization mechanisms to protect against race conditions.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but also take into account any overhead you can remove by [chunking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801635/doparallel-performance-on-a-tensor-in-r/50804071#50804071).

Comment: I really appreciate your Answer! 

I would like to shoot you few more cases, if that’s fine with you.

Case 1: `big.matrix()` accepts types “Integer”, “Double” and “Character”. Is there anouther method were I can use different types (like `list()` or `new.env()`)? Is `types=””` limited to “C”-code Variables?


Case 2: Is there a way to create Shared memory inside of the `foreach()` loop for the cores? Or do I need to declare all the shared memory when creating the clusters?

Comment: I don't think you can use more types with `big.matrix`, although I suppose you could have a list of big matrices, but I don't think that can work for environments. You can create big matrices inside each worker (see e.g. `clusterEvalQ()`), but if it's supposed to be shared, why would you create it inside instead of in the main process?

Comment: And if you do create it inside the workers, you'd have to return the description to the main process.

Comment: Thanks Alexis!  The question was generall one - like i mentioned, would like to understand the package better. 

I have one last question: What would be the equivilant of your code for Linux? `doParallel` if for Windows and `doMC` for Linux? and do i need to pass the Variable using something similar like `ClusterExport()`?

Comment: `doParallel` works on both Windows and Linux, I don't think you'd have to change anything.